# Microsoft Dynamics CRM, associated entities does not pull up records

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

We have a on-prem instance of Microsoft Dynamics CRM. The associated entities in all the forms come up blank and no records show up.

[image]

Comment: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/284852/subgrids-not-loading-the-records-showing-the-link

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we ended up updating the CRM version to resolve the issue.

temporary fix was implemented by restoring a backup of the database.

Answer (score 0):

When I get this error in on-prem environments, it's usually because the database is getting pinged and queries to it are timing out.  You may want to check the database to see if it is being overwhelmed and unable to return data.